# Excel 2003 not giving me 1 decimal when the

Tags: decimal, rounding, rounding-error

I put an "if" function to give me no decimals if result is >200, if not to give me 1 decimal.  It works great, unless the result's decimal is .0, then it doesn't show me my decimal.  How can I force the decimal to show? 
Here is my function:  =IF($E$13>200,ROUND($E$13,0),ROUND($E$13,1))

Comment: If you format the cell to display as text, the .0 should stay. However, why would you want to keep a .0 value? Formatting?

Comment: It's a spreadsheet to show lab technicians what to report as a result with the correct # of integers.  Formatting won't work because values over 200 are to be reported as a whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If representing the number as text is acceptable, the following will solve your problem:

```
=IF($E$13>200,ROUND($E$13,0),IF(ROUND($E$13,0)=ROUND($E$13,1),CONCATENATE(ROUND($E$13,0),".0"),ROUND($E$13,1)))
```

If you need to use your number in future calculations, be sure to use the original number, which can be obtained via `ROUND($E$13,1)`.